# Nodejs post not accessing the directory where the files resides

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am coming from php background and now learning Nodejs. For hours now I have been trying to post for **email** and **sms** from **dashboard.html** to server side **user.js** but am having error

```
 Cannot POST /email
Cannot POST /sms
```

it seems the sms and email form post was unable to locate the file **user.js**

here is the directory structure
[image]

**both sms and email form are inside dashboard.html**

here is **dashboard.html** file

```
                            <form role="form" method="post" action="/email">


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subject" class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Email Subject">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message" class="col-md-3 control-label">Message</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message">
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->                                       
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-email" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
<i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Submit Email</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>




                            </form>





                            <form role="form" method="post" action="/sms">


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subject" class="col-md-3 control-label">Sms message</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sms_m" placeholder="sms message">
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->                                       
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-sms" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
<i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Submit sms</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>




                            </form>
```

here is **user.js** file

```
exports.email = function(req, res){

 if(req.method == "POST"){
      var post  = req.body;
      var title= post.subject;
      var mess= post.message;


console.log(title);
console.log(mess);

}



}


exports.sms = function(req, res){

 if(req.method == "POST"){
      var post  = req.body;
      var sms_message= post.sms_m;



console.log(sms_message);


}



}
```

here is **app.js**

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
//var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();


var mysql      = require('mysql');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : 'localhost',
              user     : 'root',
              password : '',
              database : 'nodejs'
            });

connection.connect();

global.db = connection;

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
key: 'user_sid',
              secret: 'keyboard catgg4443378tf',
              resave: false,
              saveUninitialized: true,
              cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
            }));



// ensure to pass session variable from page to page
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});


// development only

app.get('/', routes.index);//call for main index page


app.get('/login', routes.index);//call for login page
app.post('/login', user.login);//call for login post


app.get('/signup', user.signup);//call for signup page
app.post('/signup', user.signup);//call for signup post 


app.get('/home/dashboard', user.dashboard);//call for dashboard page after login

app.get('/home/logout', user.logout);//call for logout
app.get('/home/profile',user.profile);//to render users profile

app.get('/email', user.email);//call for email page

app.get('/sms', user.sms);//call for email page

//Middleware
app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: "it seems the sms and email form post was unable to locate the file user.js" — If that was the problem then the program would have thrown an exception when you tried to require that file. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: My code does not have any error. The problem is posting either email or sms form from  dasboard.html  that resides inside view directory to user.js that resides inside route directory.  The form says Cannot POST /email
Cannot POST /sms

Comment: My point was that since you don't get an error, the problem is not that the file isn't found. You still need to provide a [mcve]. It does not good to show us how you are creating a couple of functions you can use as routes if you don't show us how you are hooking them up to your server.

Comment: In php its just straight forward something like http://localhost/nodejs/routes/user.php but in nodejs  its not. it involves routing etc

Comment: I have shown that on the screenshot

Comment: By "screenshot" do you mean "Scribbled visualisation of your directory structure"? That is not the same as "The **code** in `app.js` which loads the routes from `user.js`

Comment: I'm also very surprised that you get the message `Cannot POST /email` when your HTML says `action="/home/dashboard/email"`

Comment: I have added the app.js that shows the routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform the `./routes/users.js` file to properly generate and export the routes:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/email', function(req, res){
    var post  = req.body;
    var title= post.subject;
    var mess= post.message;

    console.log(title);
    console.log(mess);

    ...
    // do your logic
    ...

    res.json(response); // being response the info you want to return, commonly an object    
});


router.post('/sms', function(req, res){
    var post  = req.body;
    var sms_message= post.sms_m;

    ...
    // do your logic
    ...

    res.json(response); // being response the info you want to return, commonly an object    
}

module.exports = router;
```

Then you can import them as you are doing:

```
  var user = require('./routes/user');
  ...
  //And you will use them thus:
  app.use('/', user);
```